# how can I show image in colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I wanna show several mp4 cature images at same location(like pycharm). but cv2_imshow only show images in a row. Is there a solution ?

I wanna show several mp4 cature images at same location(like pycharm). but cv2_imshow only show images in a row

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `display.Image` class from IPython within Google Colab to display an image:

```
from IPython import display
display.Image('/content/sunflower.jpg')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: I tried your code. But It doesn't work

Comment: What is the image format (.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .heic)?

Comment: image is a one of mp4 capture image